# CheckBoxPreference - onSharedPreferenceChanged method not getting called

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

I have a couple of `CheckBoxPreferences` set up, my preference class extends `PreferenceActivity` and implements `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`
This is what I'm using to respond to people checking/unchecking the `CheckBoxPreferences`:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences P, String K) {
    if (K.equals(CheckBoxPref_KEY_HERE)) {
        MyClass.BooleanVariable = P.getBoolean("CheckBoxPref_KEY_HERE", true);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method above is never even getting called?

Comment: Much apreciated!
I almost had it sussed with your help :)
I'm not certain how to change the value of `MainClass.BooleanVariable`...
I have: `MainClass.BooleanVariable = P.isEnabled();` but that seems to **always** enable? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
checkBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) this.findPreference("CheckBoxPref_KEY_HERE");

checkBoxPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            // do your work here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the soln if you want to do something on all the preferences:

Create a class member:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
```

in your onCreate method:

```
settings = getSharedPreferences(<your_pref_name>, 0);
settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    // Do whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: Here is the unregister api
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)

Comment: Totally,not work for me.here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321637/whats-different-between-onpreferencechangelistener-and-onsharedpreferencechange/