# What's different between OnPreferenceChangeListener and OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I want to get value of a checkboxpreference. which method is suitable for listen to preference?

And what's real difference between OnPreferenceChangeListener and OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener ?!

**UPDATE**
Why onSharedPreferenceChanged not called?

```
public class Setting extends PreferenceActivity implements
        OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener // ,OnPreferenceChangeListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);// deprecated warning
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {// DO Stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        // PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefDB", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        // PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefDB", MODE_PRIVATE)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference between these 2 is that `OnPreferenceChangeListener` is a callback called **only when its** preference changes (applies to a single key), while `OnSharedPreferenceChange` is a callback called whenever **any** of the preferences in that `SharedPreferences` object changes (applies to all keys).

So, in your case, you need to use the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` with your `CheckBoxPreference`.

Here is an example:

```
Preference ckboxPref = this.findPreference(CKBOX_PREF_KEY);
ckboxPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
            Object newValue) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

The method `findPreference` does not work if you use fragments, but you aren't using any so it is fine.

Comment: Why it's not work? : @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("myKey") ...

Comment: What doesn't work? It's not called when you change that preference?

Comment: Do you call it on the `SharedPreferences` object that contains this key? Add the code in your question, please.

Comment: It doesn't call because (Probably) "myPrefDB" is not the name your PreferenceActivity uses.

Comment: Thanks,and one question : addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); that make setting UI and handle insert and update of values,using default preference DB name or my preference name? ( myPrefDB )

Comment: It uses some default preference DB name, not yours (You can get that name somehow... I don't know how, though)

Comment: Last question : your example added,does need to register and unregister ( un/registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener ) ?

Comment: No, I don't think you need to unregister when the activity is paused. After all, the preference won't changed when the activity is paused because it is only changed in this activity...

Comment: This method of implementation is bad because it gets garbage collected quickly!  Please note that you need to hold onto a handle to the listener as a member of your PreferenceFragment class otherwise the GC will eat it!

Comment: One thing to note also is that `onPreferenceChange` is called before the value is saved and `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called after the value is saved.