# SharedPreferences putBoolean on change won't work

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have an if loop when a chebkox in sharedpreferences changed status. But I'm not able to set `putBoolean("blabla", false);` when the status changed. 
For example: User hits checkbox, CB gets checked, if says `uncheck it` but it won't uncheck.

My Code:

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {    
        if(key.equals("cbSaveUsername")) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor SFEdit2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
            SFEdit2.putBoolean("cbSaveUsername", false);
            SFEdit2.commit();
        }
}
```

Can anyone tell me my mistake?

Edit: It looks like it works programatically but the tick is still in the box :o Where could be the mistake? I use it like Gunaseelan postet

Comment: can u show the piece of code where this function is called?

Comment: can you show us where you call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`?

Comment: I simply called in the `onCreate()` the `SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Unregister the listener whenever a key changes
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

For more details [onSharedPreferenceChanged not fired if change occurs in separate activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799038/onsharedpreferencechanged-not-fired-if-change-occurs-in-separate-activity/3799894#3799894)

Comment: Mhm I replaced the `getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()` by `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())` because your's is deprecated. But it won't work :/

Comment: Also refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su)

Comment: did you [register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542938/sharedpreferences-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-being-called-consistently/3104265#3104265) with onSharedPreferenceChanged?

Comment: yep, in `onCreate()` I did `SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Comment: `SharedPreferences SP = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); SP.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);` Like this?

Comment: right ;) and it seems to be just a visual thing, when I do System.out.println and put out the boolean after the change it gives the correct, but the tick is still in the box, even if the value is `false`

Comment: Ah! Okay okay got it. Just use `cb.setChecked(false);` manually if your boolean is `false`.

Comment: But how can I get the checkbox? It doesnt work with `findViewById` because it is in preferences

Comment: ref [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373131/checkboxpreference-onsharedpreferencechanged-method-not-getting-called)

Comment: `findPreference()` is deprecated

Comment: okay.. Ref [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503496/preferences-without-deprecated-methods) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272839/non-deprecated-findpreference-method-android). Surely you will get an idea.